# Android app throws IlegalStateException and crashes while i parse a String to double from an intent

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Im creating an app that takes your weight, height, gender and all that medical stuff and calculates values like IMC, calories... It has 3 activities, the first is the Main, here i ask for all the values that i said. Second one just show some results, and the last one calculates how many kgs will lose eating x value of calories per month (set by the user). The problem here is that i need two values of the second activity, the weight and the TMB (metabolism)  to calculate how many kg will lose. Im passing that values with an intent, i put them as an extra with a tag and then i get them in the last activity, i put them as an String, but they are decimals and i need them as decimals, so, when i get them as an extra and i parse them to double,  i get an IlegalStateException.

Code of the first activity (java)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //AÑADIR GENERO A DATOS TRANSFERIBLES --> DONE
        // METER TMB, CALORIAS PARA VOLUMEN, DEFINICIÓN Y MANTENIMIENTO --> DONE
        // HACER SECCIÓN ESPECIAL PARA VOLUMEN Y DEFINICION (INDICANDO KILOS A GANAR/PERDER EN X TIEMPO) --> ARREGLAR ERROR CALCULAR DEFINICIÓN **
        // ARREGLAR BUGS INICIO (QUE ESTE EL TEXTO AL LADO AL ESCRIBIR...)
        RadioGroup radioGroupActividad = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroupActividad.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int id) {
                      RadioButton radioButton = findViewById(id);
                      aN = radioButton.getText().toString();
            }
        });
    
    }
    
    
    public void sendData (View v) {
        EditText nombreApellidos = findViewById(R.id.NombreApellidos);
        EditText edad = findViewById(R.id.Edad);
        EditText altura = findViewById(R.id.altura);
        EditText peso = findViewById(R.id.peso);
        String gN = "G";
        RadioButton rbH = findViewById(R.id.hombre);
        RadioButton rbF = findViewById(R.id.mujer);
    
        if (rbH.isChecked() && !rbF.isChecked()) {
            gN = "hombre";
        }
        if (rbF.isChecked() && !rbH.isChecked()) {
            gN = "mujer";
        }
    
        /*DATOS*/
        String name = nombreApellidos.getText().toString().replace("Nombre" , "");
        String edadN = edad.getText().toString().replace("Edad","");
        String alturaN = altura.getText().toString().replace("Altura","");
        String pesoN = peso.getText().toString().replace("Peso","");
        Intent i = new Intent(this,SeeResults.class);
        String [] info  = new String[6];
        info [0] = name;
        info [1] = edadN;
        info [2] = alturaN;
        info [3] = pesoN;
        info [4] = aN;
        info [5] = gN;
        i.putExtra("data",info);
        startActivity(i);
    
    }
    public void onClickElement (View v) {
        int idElement = v.getId();
        if (idElement == R.id.peso) {
            EditText peso = findViewById(R.id.peso);
            peso.setText("");
        }
        if (idElement == R.id.altura) {
            EditText altura = findViewById(R.id.altura);
            altura.setText("");
        }
        if (idElement == R.id.NombreApellidos) {
            EditText Nombre = findViewById(R.id.NombreApellidos);
            Nombre.setText("");
        }
        if (idElement == R.id.Edad) {
            EditText Edad = findViewById(R.id.Edad);
            Edad.setText("");
        }
    }
    
    String aN;
}
```

Code of the second activity:

```
public class SeeResults extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_see_results);
        dataTransfered = new String[6];
        TextView imc = findViewById(R.id.Imc);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String [] data = i.getStringArrayExtra("data");
        dataTransfered = data;
        String actividadF = dataTransfered[4];
        String genero = dataTransfered[5];
        double actividadFNumero = 0;
        switch (actividadF) {
            case "Poca":
            actividadFNumero = 1.1;
            break;
            case "Regular":
            actividadFNumero = 1.3;
            break;
            case "Bastante":
            actividadFNumero = 1.5;
            break;
            case "Mucha":
            actividadFNumero = 1.7;
            break;
        }
        double peso = Double.parseDouble(dataTransfered[3]);
        double altura = Double.parseDouble(dataTransfered[2]) / 100;
        int edad = Integer.parseInt(dataTransfered [1]);
        double IMC = Math.round (peso / (altura * altura));
        double TMB = 0;
        if (genero.equals("hombre")) {
            TMB = ((10 * peso) + (6.25 * (altura * 100) ) -  (5 * edad ) + 5) * actividadFNumero;
        }
        if (genero.equals("mujer")) {
            TMB = ((10 * peso) + (6.25 * (altura * 100) ) -  (5 * edad) - 161) * actividadFNumero;
        }
        Log.d("ActividadFisica",actividadF);
        Log.d("ActividadFisicaNumero", String.valueOf(actividadFNumero));
        Log.d("Genero",genero);
    
        i.putExtra("TMB",String.valueOf(TMB));
        i.putExtra("Peso",String.valueOf(peso));
        imc.setText("Tu IMC es : " +  IMC + "\n"  +   "Tu TMB es : " + TMB + "\n" + "\n" + "Calorias definición : " + (TMB - 500) + "\n"  + "\n" +  "Calorias en volumen: " + (TMB + 500));
    
    }
    
    public void goBack (View v) {
     Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(i);
    }
    
    public void calcularDefinicion (View v) {
         i = new Intent(this, CalcularDefinicion.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    
    String [] dataTransfered;
    Intent i;
}
```

Code of the last activity :

```
public class CalcularDefinicion extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calcular_definicion);
        tiempoDef = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TiempoDef);
        caloriasDef = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CaloriasDef);
        textoInicio = findViewById(R.id.pesoEmpezarDef);
        textoAcabar = findViewById(R.id.pesoAcabarDef);
    
    }
    
    public void calcularDef (View v) {
       int calorias = Integer.parseInt(caloriasDef.getText().toString().replace("Calorias",""));
       int tiempo = Integer.parseInt(tiempoDef.getText().toString().replace("Tiempo",""));
        Log.d("caloriasNumero",String.valueOf(calorias));
        Log.d("tiempoNumero",String.valueOf(tiempo));
       Intent i = getIntent();
       double TMB = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("TMB"));
       double peso = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("Peso"));
       Log.d("TMB",String.valueOf(TMB));
       Log.d("Peso",String.valueOf(peso));
       double pesoPerdido = (TMB - calorias) * (tiempo / 30);
       double pesoFinal = peso - pesoPerdido;
    
       textoAcabar.setText(textoAcabar.getText() + " " + pesoFinal);
    }
    
    EditText caloriasDef;
    EditText tiempoDef;
    TextView textoInicio, textoAcabar;

}
```

STACKTRACE

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.example.calculoimc, PID: 32693
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
> android:onClick at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:473)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506) at
> com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483) at
> android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334) at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)  at
> com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211) 
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)  at
> android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)  at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)  at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object
> reference at
> jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
> at
> jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
> at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:543) at
> com.example.calculoimc.CalcularDefinicion.calcularDef(CalcularDefinicion.java:31)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468) 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)  at
> com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211) 
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)  at
> android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)  at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)  at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

I checked that it all the values are  a DOUBLE and did not have any value  like "Calories: 43" and was only 43, thats what i do in this part of the code in the last activity:

```
int calorias = Integer.parseInt(caloriasDef.getText().toString().replace("Calorias",""));
int tiempo = Integer.parseInt(tiempoDef.getText().toString().replace("Tiempo","");
```

The TMB and the weight are just numbers, the TMB is calculated and the weight is put just as a number.

Also, the activity is registered in the manifest, i dont think there is the problem but i checked it anyways, i searched and searched around all the internet but i could not figure out what is wrong.

Comment: When posting, question, put the StackTrace, its the best source of information, even if its long. Also, try to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Done , i think i pasted it correctly  and all the info is there, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, you've set `onClick` method of a button in one of your xml file with its default name as **`onClick`**, with the intention of connecting the button click event to the **`onClickElement`** method that you defined in your *MainActivity.java*.

Either change `onClickElement` to `onClick` in your activity or `onClick` to `onClickElement` in your xml so that the declared and defined symbols match.

#### Correction Update

After your comment, I relooked at the exception message and seems like you are right. The actual problem occurs when getting data in your `CalcularDefinicion`'s `onCreate` method. There you try to get the sent data from the previous activity but you get null because in the previous activitiy you send a new intent that does not have any data.

**SeeResults** class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // You get the intent here from the main activity
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String [] data = i.getStringArrayExtra("data");
    ...
    // After processing values you use the same intent to send data
    i.putExtra("TMB",String.valueOf(TMB));
    i.putExtra("Peso",String.valueOf(peso));
}

/*
But when you start the CalcularDefinicion activity you create a new intent
and all the data you put in the onCreate method has gone. Now you send
nothing to the CalcularDefinicion activity, hence you obviously will get null.
*/
public void calcularDefinicion (View v) {
    i = new Intent(this, CalcularDefinicion.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Here are some solutions for you.

##### Solution 1

Set the button's `onClikListener` within the `onCreate` method so that you can get access to the intent that you've set the data for `CalcularDefinicion` activity.

```
public class SeeResults extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String [] data = i.getStringArrayExtra("data");
        ...
        double IMC = Math.round (peso / (altura * altura));
        double TMB = 0;
        if (genero.equals("hombre")) {
            TMB = ((10 * peso) + (6.25 * (altura * 100) ) -  (5 * edad ) + 5) * actividadFNumero;
        }
        if (genero.equals("mujer")) {
            TMB = ((10 * peso) + (6.25 * (altura * 100) ) -  (5 * edad) - 161) * actividadFNumero;
        }
        ...
        
        i.putExtra("TMB",String.valueOf(TMB));
        i.putExtra("Peso",String.valueOf(peso));
        imc.setText("Tu IMC es : " +  IMC + "\n"  +   "Tu TMB es : " + TMB + "\n" + "\n" + "Calorias definición : " + (TMB - 500) + "\n"  + "\n" +  "Calorias en volumen: " + (TMB + 500));
        
        calcularDefinicionButton.setOnClickListener(() v -> {
            startActivity(i);
        });
    }
}
```

##### Solution 2

Leave the `onCLick` implementation as is and declare a discrete intent for `CalcularDefinicion` activity.

```
public class SeeResults extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final Intent calcularIntent = new Intent(this, CalcularDefinicion.class);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String [] data = i.getStringArrayExtra("data");
        ...
        double IMC = Math.round (peso / (altura * altura));
        double TMB = 0;
        if (genero.equals("hombre")) {
            TMB = ((10 * peso) + (6.25 * (altura * 100) ) -  (5 * edad ) + 5) * actividadFNumero;
        }
        if (genero.equals("mujer")) {
            TMB = ((10 * peso) + (6.25 * (altura * 100) ) -  (5 * edad) - 161) * actividadFNumero;
        ...
        calcularIntent.putExtra("TMB",String.valueOf(TMB));
        calcularIntent.putExtra("Peso",String.valueOf(peso));
        imc.setText("Tu IMC es : " +  IMC + "\n"  +   "Tu TMB es : " + TMB + "\n" + "\n" + "Calorias definición : " + (TMB - 500) + "\n"  + "\n" +  "Calorias en volumen: " + (TMB + 500));
        
    }
    
    public void goBack (View v) {
        // Don't hesitate to create new intents for each different cases
        Intent backIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(backIntent);
    }
    
    public void calcularDefinicion (View v) {
        startActivity(calcularIntent);
    }
}
```

##### Watch it!

Finally there is one more thing to consider. Things may fail and may not result as expected. That's why you should take your precautions as a programmer to make sure the failable data does exist and wholesome.

```
public class CalcularDefinicion extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    ...
    
    public void calcularDef (View v) {
        int calorias = Integer.parseInt(caloriasDef.getText().toString().replace("Calorias",""));
        int tiempo = Integer.parseInt(tiempoDef.getText().toString().replace("Tiempo",""));
        Log.d("caloriasNumero",String.valueOf(calorias));
        Log.d("tiempoNumero",String.valueOf(tiempo));
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // ATTENTION to this part!
        String TMBstring = i.getStringExtra("TMB");
        String pesoString = i.getStringExtra("Peso");
        // Always check the nullity of the data you get from intent because
        // somehow if the data don't exist it will return null by default
        if (TMBstring == null || TMBstring.isEmpty()) {
            // Can't continue without data, handle this unexpected case
            return;
        }
        if (pesoString == null || pesoString.isEmpty()) {
            // Can't continue without data, handle this unexpected case
            return;
        }
        // If the program flow reaches here, then all the data exist and you
        // can continue to process further.
        double TMB = Double.parseDouble(TMBstring);
        double peso = Double.parseDouble(pesoString);
        Log.d("TMB",String.valueOf(TMB));
        Log.d("Peso",String.valueOf(peso));
        double pesoPerdido = (TMB - calorias) * (tiempo / 30);
        double pesoFinal = peso - pesoPerdido;
        
        textoAcabar.setText(textoAcabar.getText() + " " + pesoFinal);
    }
    
    EditText caloriasDef;
    EditText tiempoDef;
    TextView textoInicio, textoAcabar;
    
}
```

Comment: I checked in the xml and all the buttons have their own `onClick` method  defined in the java file , no one has the default `onClick`.

Comment: Correct, that was the problem, one small thing, i created the `Intent` that sends you to the activity `CalcularDefinicion` but, in the location it was created (outside onCreate) it was giving me the same error but this time i could not enter to `SeeResults` class. Anyway, i solved it just creating the intent inside the onCreate  and setting an `OnClickListener` for the button also inside and now everything works without any problem, i will take in count to add a conditional always to check if the data is null so it does not crash, thanks for the help :).